# Limit the number of visible pages shown in pagination in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pagination

My pagination System currently looks like this:

[What my pagination system currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGm4q.png)

However, I only want 10 page links to appear at a time. Instead of all of the links.

I have this code:

```
const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
const content = document.getElementById('content');

let pageIndex = 0;
let itemsPerPage = 3;
let finalPage = Math.ceil(items.length / itemsPerPage) - 1;
console.log(finalPage)

loadItems();
function loadItems() {
  content.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = pageIndex * itemsPerPage; i < (pageIndex * itemsPerPage) + itemsPerPage; i++) {
    if (!items[i]) break;
    const item = document.createElement('div');
    item.innerHTML = `
        <div>
            <img src="${items[i].src}"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button>${items[i].desc}</button>
        </div>
    `;
    content.append(item);
  }
  firstPage();
  minusPage();
  loadPageNav();
  plusPage();
  lastPage();
}


function loadPageNav() {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length / itemsPerPage; i++) {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.classList.add('btn');
    button.innerHTML = i + 1;
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      pageIndex = e.target.innerHTML - 1;
      loadItems();
    });
    nav.append(button);
  }
}

function plusPage() {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.classList.add('btn');
  button.innerHTML = "&#8250;";
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pageIndex = pageIndex + 1;
    loadItems();
  });

  nav.append(button);

  if (pageIndex === finalPage) {
    button.disabled = true;
  }
}

function minusPage() {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.classList.add('btn');
  button.innerHTML = "&#8249;";
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pageIndex = pageIndex - 1;
    loadItems();
  });
  nav.append(button);

  if (pageIndex === 0) {
    button.disabled = true;
  }
}

function firstPage() {
  nav.innerHTML = "";
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.classList.add('btn');
  button.innerHTML = "&laquo";
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pageIndex = 0;
    loadItems();
  });

  nav.append(button);

  if (pageIndex === 0) {
    button.disabled = true;
  }
}

function lastPage() {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.classList.add('btn');
  button.innerHTML = "&raquo";
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pageIndex = finalPage;
    loadItems();
  });

  nav.append(button);

  if (pageIndex === finalPage) {
    button.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

This code produces the output shown above. However, I want to produce this output:

[What my pagination system should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkpbT.png)

Comment: A mere "I want" is not a question suitable for this site. What have you tried to achieve this, and what specific problem did you run into?

Comment: I have looked at multiple sites and videos. However, I have not found anything that works correctly.

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding, the loadPageNav function is the one that draws your page numbers. Pay attention to the maximum value your for loop goes too.

For example if you have 100 items (items.length = 100) and want to display only 5 items per page then
items.length / itemsPerPage is 100 / 5 = 20.

You have 20 pages and in your loop you create and add a button for each of those. If you want to limit the number of buttons drawn, then you need to limit the maximum value you assign to i.

Comment: I want to know how to limit the maximum value of i, whilst also ensuring the correct pages are show, such as 'Page 5, Page 6, Page 7, Page 8, Page 9', instead of the first 4 pages being shown and page 9 being shown

Comment: You can start by understanding what a for loop is then. Here's a link that explains it: 
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-for-loops/#:~:text=For%20Loops%20in%20JavaScript,as%20those%20conditions%20are%20met.

Comment: How can I limit the minimum and maximum values of i, to ensure only 5 pages are shown